# Why does .set_index() used in single line return DatatimeIndex, but seperate lines returns RangeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con, parse_dates=["time"]).set_index("time")
type(df_aq.index)
```

Why does this set index as DatetimeIndex (pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex) while the code below returns a RangeIndex (pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex):

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con, parse_dates=["time"])
df.set_index("time")
type(df_aq.index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line you are setting the index while reading and saving it in the  dataframe `df`, but in the code below where you get the `RangeIndex`, you are not saving the index but just temporarily assigning it.

That is why when you do `type(df_aq.index)` , you get to see the type of the original df and not the `time` column being assigned as index.

Either use:

```
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
```

or

```
df = df.set_index("time")
```

both should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
df.set_index("time")
```

to

```
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
```

By default inplace is set to false.